# Is there a script to fix opentelemetry lint errors?

Tags: open-telemetry, golangci-lint

When running the `make golint` target in opentelemetry-collector-contrib, sometimes a lint error will appear.  It seems like the kind of lint-check which could be easily fixed as well, but `make gofmt` will not fix such.

Is there a way to use one of the tools vendored by `make install-tools` in `GIT_REPO_ROOT/.tools` to automatically reformat the project in a way which makes the golangci-lint happy?

**-- details --**

The specific error is `` File is not `gci`-ed with --skip-generated -s standard,default,prefix(github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib) ``

neither `make gofmt`, `./.tools/goimports -w -local "github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib"` work for this, and

The particular command in the make target manifesting this problem is `.tools/golangci-lint run --allow-parallel-runners --build-tags integration`

However, none of these flags seem to be valid for the gci tool

```
❯ ./.tools/gci --skip-generated -s standard,default,prefix\(github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib\)
Error: unknown flag: --skip-generated
Usage:
  gci [-diff | -write] [--local localPackageURLs] path... [flags]
  gci [command]

Available Commands:
  completion  Generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
  diff        Prints a git style diff to STDOUT
  help        Help about any command
  print       Outputs the formatted file to STDOUT
  write       Formats the specified files in-place

Flags:
  -d, --diff            display diffs instead of rewriting files
  -h, --help            help for gci
  -l, --local strings   put imports beginning with this string after 3rd-party packages, separate imports by comma
  -v, --version         version for gci
  -w, --write           write result to (source) file instead of stdout

Use "gci [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, need to add the write command and replace `{}` with your filename

```
 ./.tools/gci write {} --skip-generated -s standard,default,prefix\(github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib\)
```